# Smarter latex justification to avoid large spaces

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The default format in latex for paragraphs is fully justified, where the first word of a line touches the left margin and the last word of a line is flush with the right margin.

This is nice for lines that are about as long as the width of the text area, but if there are few words, LaTeX will create large amounts of whitespace between the words so they touch both sides.

In a document editor like Word or Writer, when I set the format to fully justified, this only applies to lines within a certain range of the edge as in almost every line is fully justified unless a line is specifically shorter and in that case appears left justified.

Here's an example image comparing the two:

[image]

Is there a way to do the equivalent justification in LaTeX?

Comment: The default output from LaTeX *is* justified, but not in the way you show it. It would be really helpful if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that reproduces the LaTeX output you provide. This should start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is **not** the default format in latex for paragraphs! Could you tell where you got that information? If it's from some online resource, it might be worthwile to try to get that changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, in any kind of typesetting scenario, any time, any where, TeX wins over Word, LibreOffice, Open Office etc. all combined. I say unfortunately because it would be a good pressure on the TeX side to take the competition seriously if any of these tools could implement TeX like optimization schemes. Right now, it's a matter of second place among those tools. Having said that, you are without a doubt, modifying some settings or a package is modifying erroneously. It's a typical MS Word artifact when you justify the paragraphs but no way in TeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are most likely loading a package or manually setting the value of `\parfillskip`. The definition of `\parfillskip`, from [TeX for the Impatient](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf) (section on **Shaping paragraphs**, p 111):

> This parameter specifies the
>   horizontal glue that TEX inserts at the end of a paragraph. The
>   default value of `\parfillskip` is `0pt plus 1fil`, which causes the last
>   line of a paragraph to be ﬁlled out with blank space. A value of `0pt`
>   forces TEX to end the last line of a paragraph at the right margin.

As an example, this is the effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fourscore}{\noindent Four score and seven years ago our fathers 
  brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, 
  and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.\par}
\begin{document}
\fourscore
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
\fourscore
\end{document}
```

So, restoring it can either be done by finding the "offending" package, or adding

```
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

to your preamble. Without more information, it's difficult to assess how else to fix the problem.

Comment: TeX will scream about `Underfull \hbox`, right?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: You heard that too?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the solution that was propose did not work for me. I had spent hours trying to remove these unwanted gaps in the text. I would like to share how I solved my problem, for those who are still having this issue.

I used latex for my thesis and when I ended a paragraph, I used `\linebreak` command but it was a huge mistake that took hours to figure out. If you are using `\justify` command to fully justify your text in your document, then use `\\` to end your paragraphs *not* `\linebreak`. With just this small change, all your unwanted spaces are removed.

Hope this helps for some of you still having this problem!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Paragraphs should not end with ``\\``, but by leaving an empty line after them.